# Is it possible to emulate object methods in C?

Tags: c, oop, object, emulation, self-reference

Is it possible to emulate object methods in C? I'd like to be able self-reference a structure as a parameter to a member function argument e.g.:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    int (*save)(struct foo *);
};

int
save_foo(struct foo *bar) {
    // do stuff.
}

struct foo *
create_foo() {
    struct foo *bar = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    bar->save = save_foo;

    return bar;
}

int
main() {
    struct foo *bar = create_foo();

    bar->a = 10;
    bar->save();
}
```

Where, `bar->save()`, actually calls `save_foo(bar)`. Seems like a long shot, but it'd be pretty slick :)

Comment: Well, since every other language emulates object methods, and most of them are implemented at least partially in C... (This will be helpful: www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf )

Comment: If you want C++, why not just use a C++ compiler?

Comment: @BoPersson - Because the OO he's trying to implement isn't C++'s object model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. There are object-oriented libraries in C, but they pass the "`this`" object to the "method" explicitly as in

```
bar->save(bar);
```

See the Berkeley DB C API for an example of this style, but do consider using C++ or Objective-C if you want to do OO in a C-like language.

Comment: You _can_ say `int save(struct foo *obj) { obj->save(obj); }` which simplifies the call to `save(bar)` - not the "correct order" but close enough, and without the repetition.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: the repetition is still there, but now wrapped in the `save` function (and in freestanding wrappers for all other "methods").

Comment: How about `#define M(object, method, ...) ((object)->method(object, __VA_ARGS__))` ?

Comment: @ChrisLutz: that evaluates the macro argument `object` twice, so it's not reliable.

Comment: While that's true, I don't usually write code in any OO language that looks like `(x++)->method`. Nothing is "unreliable" if you clearly document its limitations.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: I commonly write that kind of code, and so do others; one particular instance of it is constructor chaining.

Comment: this is what I currently do, I just got to wondering... I'll stick with C :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no. The reference to the function in C is simply a pointer to where it resides, and when you're calling it, you're just taking the pointer from the struct, jumping there and continuing execution without any knowledge about context or stack, so there's nowhere to take "this" from.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "Yes."

The proof is that the first C++ compilers were not compilers at all. They simply translated C++ code into C code. The [CFront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) compiler did this.

I see from the other answers that I probably misunderstood your question. No, the syntax you wrote in the question will not work in C. You'd need to write your own type of preprocessor/translator to convert the call from `bar->save()` to `foo_save(bar)` or even `C3fooF4save(bar)`.

Comment: The question is not about using OOP paradigm (which can be done in any language, albeit shouldn't). The question is about a particular syntactic construct, which, to my knowledge, is not possible without a custom (and a very clever) preprocessor. Like, yes, CFront.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pass `bar` to the `save` function pointer, and you'll have what C++ does under-the-hood (invisibly passes `this` as the first parameter to the method). You can't get the `this` (aka `bar`) passed automatically in C.

Comment: This is closer to what Objective-C does under the hood - the method lookup is resolved at runtime via a function pointer, while in C++ it would be resolved at compile time, i.e. C++ code would be closer to `save_foo(bar)`, with no function pointer indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just awkward. I've implemented objects in Fortran77 using named common blocks.

In C, structs are probably the way to go. If you don't want to pass structs around, you could make them global and access them that way. Whatever work-around you choose, comment it well!

Sometimes one has to use C and doesn't have C++, Objective C, etc. available. I like Java and C# for OO programming, but sometimes you have to make do.